# docker buildx takes longer time to build multi arch images - ARM64 and AMD64 than single arch

Tags: docker, dockerfile, artifact, apple-silicon, buildx

using docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64 takes 5 times longer than
docker build .

I'm running the command using jenkins pipeline on a amd64 slave.
Is there any way to build the image faster?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Facing the same now.